# jQuery from google CDN is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use jQuery in my webpage. I don't want to download it, so I am including it from Google's CDN.

When I run the page, the jQuery is not working.

Can anyone tell me whether the problem relies in jQuery or in my code.

Here is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
cars=new Array("Mercedes","Volvo","BMW","porche");
phones=new Array('Samsung','Nokia','Iphone');

populateSelect();

$(function() {

  $('#cat').change(function(){
    populateSelect();
});

});


function populateSelect(){
cat=$('#cat').val();
$('#item').html('');


if(cat=='car'){
    cars.forEach(function(t) { 
        $('#item').append('<option>'+t+'</option>');
    });
}

if(cat=='phone'){
    phones.forEach(function(t) {
        $('#item').append('<option>'+t+'</option>');
    });
}

} 
</script>
</head>

<body>
<select id="cat">
<option value="car">car</option>
<option value="phone">phone</option>
</select>

<select id="item">

</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call populateSelect() which tries to access your select tag when the DOM hasn't even loaded yet.

Move the function call into your DOM Ready event handler:

```
$(function() {
  populateSelect();

  $('#cat').change(function(){
    populateSelect();
  });
});
```

The next time, open your browser's **developer console**! It will clearly show the error.

Comment: @sapan You're welcome! Please read on [how to accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/191400), so you can start accepting answers from this and the other questions from you :)